# PHP Dependency Injector or Factory?

Tags: php, design-patterns, dependency-injection, factory-pattern, service-locator

I'm using Zend Framework 1 and [Pimple](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/) dependency injector. After watching some Google Guice presentations on YouTube, I'm not sure if I'm really using DI and not a simple factory. The way I'm making use of my Pimple injector is by asking it to give me an instance of some object based on a string key registered and associated with the object:

```
class SomeService extends AbstactService {
   /** @var Pimple $injector Inherited from base class */
   protected $injector;

   public function save(array $data) {
      $model = $this->injector["some-model"];

      if (empty($data["id"])) {
         $model->insert($data);
      } else {
         $model->update($data);
      }
   }
}
```

The member variable $injector is created and configured at bootstrap, and sent to my AbstractService class, so all concrete services inherit it.

So by the way that $injector is used here, even though it uses Pimple (a DI container), is this implementing DI pattern or something else (factory or maybe service locator) ?

**Update**

Some further info: I'm using Zend Framework (MVC) building a nutrition/exercise website.

I think what is confusing me is how to create some object inside a method, where that object is only needed for that method, and the method takes some run-time arguments. For example, the SomeService class gets instantiated by the container in my controller. Then I call SomeService::save() passing in $data. Where and how would $model be created? Suppose $model is only used in that particular method, so that it wouldn't make sense to make it a class member, how could that be injected by the container?

Comment: Looks like a SL to me. Instead of injecting whatever specific thing it is that you need you are injecting an entire container. It would be impossible to tell what the dependencies are because of this. `E_TOO_MUCH_MAGIC`. Basically you are violating [LoD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Comment: That's the conclusion I had come to... so my next question is: how can I make better use of that injector?

Comment: How are you actually using it now? Are you using the injector to wire up dependencies? Do your classes even have dependencies? Are you mostly using inheritance, or composition, to handle dependencies?

Using it as a service locator isn't necessarily a bad thing as long as it's in a certain context. For example, Laravel's facades use its DiC/IoC as a service locator.

Would also help if you told us what kind of application pattern you're using (e.g. MVC or something else)

Comment: Relevant #1: http://ralphschindler.com/2012/10/10/di-dic-service-locator-redux/comment-page-1#comment-90074

Comment: Relevant #2: https://github.com/rdlowrey/Auryn

Comment: BAM! That article pretty much cleared it out for me. Looks like I was a bit confused about the diff between DiC VS SL, but mostly not sure when to best use each. I started thinking that maybe a better design would make it easier to use a DiC, but I'm leaning towards the other conclusion made by the article: in my particular case, a SL is a more logical choice. Thanks!